# Wifi not working in windows if thunderbolt display is connected

Tags: wifi, windows, bootcamp, thunderbolt-display

I had to install windows 7 on my macbook air (...) and I'm having trouble getting it to work with the thunderbolt display.

As soon as the display is connected, the wifi doesn't work anymore. Device manager shows the broadcom wifi device with a warning sign. It works nicely  when I reboot without the display plugged in.

Of course I've installed the newest Bootcamp drivers!

Is this a known problem?
Any suggestions?

(If it helps, I'm also having trouble getting my wireless trackpad and wireless keyboard to work at all with windows 7, might be related..)

(un)fortunately I don't know jack about windows anymore because I didn't use it seriously for at least 10 years.

Answer (score 2):

I have this exact same problem but in MacOS X Mountain Lion.  The minute I unplug the thunderbolt/minidisplayport, the wifi starts working again.

I found a weird solution on the internet from another Macbook Air owner witht eh same problem as us: access your router and change the channel to 1, or 2, or any other number that works.  For some reason, plugging in the cable disrupts the wifi signal entering the Macbook.

This seems to be a common problem and this seems to be the only solution that works, as many users have tried with different cables and different OS.  Hopefully Apple will provide a firmware update to fix this for good as not always can we access the router (like at my work).  However, as of today (I updated my OS to 10.8.4), this problem has not been fixed properly.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and found a quick and dirty solution.
Boot into Windows with the Thunderbolt Display connected and visit the device manager and delete the drivers with the warning sign.

In my case, windows immediately installed the drivers automatically and it worked right away.

Answer (score 0):

Apple say that certain monitors will interfere with wifi, [as stated here](http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201542). That wouldn't explain why it seems to only affect *apple* products! But does explain why lowering the wifi channel to 1 might help (it says to avoid 11-14). It also suggests moving to 5GHz instead of 2.5GHz may alleviate the problem.

Somebody else suggests that if you use a genuine apple Thunderbolt adapter/display then it'll be OK too.